# Wait till for completes using jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make this code wait till the form gets a response. the form must submit to recurly and receive a response from recurly before it can go on.

if there is a way to assure there is a response would be nice kinda like success: or error:

```
$("#pay_window").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Submit Payment": function(){
                    $("#PaymentForm").submit();



                 <--- NEED A WAIT FUNCTION HERE --->



                    var dialogbox = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/payment",
                        data: $(this).find([company_id, billing_email, first_name, last_name, recurly_token, selected_plan, account]).serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            dialogbox.dialog("close");
                            alert('Payment Completed')

                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just pass your wait function to `complete` option of `$.ajax`

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, you don't wait, the rest of the code keeps running, and the success or error callback will be called upon success or error. So anything that must happen after the request, must happen inside a callback. Or you can return a deferred object and handle that callback later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form submit is *essentially* the same thing as a post to the endpoint specified by the form's "action" attribute (or to the page containing the form). You could gather the form data and make a post (via jQuery to recurly) and then use jQuery's Deferred object methods ('then', 'done', 'fail', etc.) or use $.ajax and the success/error options...Granted this won't work in IE 7/8/9 (there's no access to a FormData object).

Given this rather over simplistic form:

```
<form id="foo" action="http://example.com/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="a">
</form>
```

One could grab the input and create a 'FormData' object:

```
var $foo = $('#foo'),
    formData = new FormData($foo[0]),


$.ajax({
    url: $foo.attr('action'),
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        /* do what you want */},
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        /* do what you've got to */ }
 });
```